# Should I use @Scheduled or sleep in rest controller?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, scheduled-tasks

I need to invoke some delayed action after calling my rest controller from frontend. For example after calling endpoint /controller with method Update. I want to get response status OK and in the controller call scheduler which will execute some update function on my entities in database after 15 minutes after call endpoint only once. I just want to simple change 2 boolean fields with delay. What should I use? @Schedule annotation or just sleep or maybe something else? I would be grateful for all advices.

Best regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Scheduled is meant for periodic execution of a certain method. For what you want you should use the `ScheduledExecutor` class. See the documentation for more details https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html

It has two methods, the `scheduleWithFixedDelay` method is the one you want to use.

EDIT: Heres an example

```
final ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
executorService.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
         //Do you database save here
    }
}, 0, 15, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

EDIT 2:

Maybe its simpler to just use the `schedule()` method instead, since you are only doing one update. The example above is for when you have multiple actions that must each be done successively with a fixed delay of 15 minuten between executions. For only one execution you could use:

```
executorService.schedule(() -> database.save(), 15, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
executorService.shutdown();
```

the code `() -> database.save()` is called a lambda expression. 
calling `shutdown` after the schedule call is important or else you might get memory leaks. The `shutdown()` method will wait for the thread in the executorService queue to be executed after which it will destroy the thread used.

Comment: @SnoozeSnoze you're welcome, please accept my post as the answer if this solves your problem by clicking the OK sign.